# Dynamically show and hide imagebuttons inside row of listview

Tags: android, row, show, imagebutton, listactivity

How can i show and hide some imagebuttons inside a row of a listview on listactivity?
Ive some list of packages and want show buttons like install and uninstall. But when a package is installed only uninstall button is showed. If click uninstall, i want to hide uninstall button and show install button.
i reference every row in a loop like this:

`v = vi.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);`

and reference button like this

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.descargar);
            ib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

nothing happened. Any suggestions?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheriting the ArrayAdapter class and overwrite the getView function.
The getView function always called, when row is displayed.

Create class for rows:

```
public class MyRow {
   public boolean installed;
}
```

Implement ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter<MyRow> {

@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    // get actual row item.
    MyRow item = (MyRow)getItem(position);
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.install);
    ImageButton uib = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.uninstall);

     if (item.installed) {
         ib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         uib.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
         ib.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         uib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }    

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

Check this tutorial on how to implement ListAdapter and how to recycle views.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: works first time. How can i refresh listview to update imagebuttons when one is clicked?For example, when user clicks install button. Thanks.

Comment: If dataset is changed, will call this function: adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your code, but try this:

```
View v  = getListView().getChildAt(i);
```

Then proceed to do as you did:

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.descargar);
        ib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This worked for me. Hope this help.

Comment: i tried this but does not work. I think property in imagebutton is ok. But how can i force to redraw rows with new properties? Thanks.